# React Module not found: Error: You attempted to import

Tags: reactjs

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /User/Developer/app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: I think this maybe a tsconfig error

Comment: did you fixed this error?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I have found so far is to disable fast refresh. Put this line in the env file FAST_REFRESH=false.

Comment: I also found from internet seems only disable fast refresh could work. did you found another solution? @AK96

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the given package or folder and put it in the src

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).